# map expression in case clause in scala pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a configuration value that matches to one of the values in a map and depending on to which it matches i take an action. Here is some sample code of what i am trying to do

```
val x = 1         // or 2 or 3

val config = Map("c1"-> 1, "c2"-> 2, "c3"-> 3)

x match {
  case config("c1") =>
    println("1")
  case config("c2") =>
    println("2")
  case config("c3") =>
    println("3")
}
```

Now this should print `1` because `config("c1")` evaluates to `1` but it gives error

```
error: value config is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
                case config("c1") =>
```

Similarly for the other 2 cases. Why should i have an unapply here? Any pointers?

Comment: `case` does an `upapply` or `unapplySeq` on all  the patterns you provide. That's how it does the matching, taking the first match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression like that looks like an [extractor](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112), hence the message about `unapply/unapplySeq` methods. If you don't want to use an extractor but just want to match against a plain value, you need to store that value in a stable identifier - you can't use an arbitrary expression as a match case:

```
val case1 = config("c1")
x match {
  case case1 => println("1")
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can i write an extractor for a map?

Comment: What do you mean? What is it you want to do?

Comment: `case case1` should be replaced with `case <backtick>case1<backtick>` or `case1` should be in title case like `Case1` .

Comment: You can name a value in title case if you want to

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, in Scala, `x match {case config("c1")` gets translated to `config.unapply(x)` with the branching dependent on the result of the unapply method. As **Imm** already mentioned in his answer, this isn't the case for stable identifiers (literals and `val`), and I'd encourage you to use his solution.

Nevertheless, to show you how you could solve the problem using extractors, I'd like to post a different solution:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  object config {
    val configData = Map("c1" -> 1, "c2" -> 2, "c3" -> 3)

    def unapply(value: Int): Option[String] = configData find (_._2 == value) map (_._1)
  }

  1 to 4 foreach {
    case config("c1") => println("1")
    case config("c2") => println("2")
    case config("c3") => println("3")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
}
```

I changed the `match` for a `foreach` to show the different results, but this has no effect on the implementation. This would print:

```
1
2
3
no match
```

As you can see, `case config("c1")` now calls the unapply method and checks whether the result is `Some("c1")`. Note that this is inverse to how you'd use a map: The key is searched according to the value. However, this makes sense: If in the map, `"c1"` and `"c2"` both map to `1`, then `1` matches both, the same way `_` matches everything, in our case even `4` which is not configured.

Here's also a very brief [tutorial on extractors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html). I don't find it particularly good, because both, the returned type and the argument type are `Int`, but it might help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, with `x match { case config("c1") => ...`, scala looks for an extractor by the name of `config` (something with an `unapply` method that takes a single value and returns an Optional value); Making pattern matching work this way seems like an abuse of the pattern, and I would not use an extractor for this.

Personally, I would recommend one of the following:

```
if (x == config("c1"))
  println("1")
else if (x == config("c2"))
  println("2")
else ...
```

Or, if you're set on using a match statement, you can use conditionals like this:

```
x match {
  case _ if x == config("c1") =>
    println("1")
  case _ if x == config("c2") =>
    println("2")
  case _ if x == config("c3") =>
    println("3")
}
```

Not as clean; unfortunately, there isn't a way to invoke a method call literally where the extractor goes. You can use back-ticks to tell scala "match against the value of this variable" (rather than default behavior, which would yield the value named as that variable):

```
val (c1,c2,c3) = (config("c1"), config("c2"), config("c3"))
x match {
  case `c1` =>
    println("1")
  case `c2` =>
    println("2")
  case `c3` =>
    println("3")
}
```

Finally, if your goal is to reverse-apply a map, maybe try this instead?

```
scala> Map("a" -> 1).map { case (k,v) => (v,k) }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a)
```