# Scala - not a case class nor does it have method .unapply

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, case, unapply

I am quite new to Scala and got a few unresolved problems with the following code:

```
   object exprs{
      println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

      def show(e: Expr): String = e match {
        case Number(x) => x.toString
        case Sum(l, r) => show(l) + " + " + show(r)
      }

      show(Sum(Number(1), Number(44)))
    }

    trait Expr {
      def isNumber: Boolean
      def isSum: Boolean
      def numValue: Int
      def leftOp: Expr
      def rightOp: Expr
      def eval: Int = this match {
        case Number(n) => n
        case Sum(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
      }
    }

    class Number(n: Int) extends Expr {
      override def isNumber: Boolean = true

      override def isSum: Boolean = false

      override def numValue: Int = n

      override def leftOp: Expr = throw new Error("Number.leftOp")

      override def rightOp: Expr = throw new Error("Number.rightOp")
    }

    class Sum(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr {
      override def isNumber: Boolean = false

      override def isSum: Boolean = true

      override def numValue: Int = e1.eval + e2.eval

      override def leftOp: Expr = e1

      override def rightOp: Expr = e2
    }
```

I get the following errors:

**Error:** object Number is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member

**Error:** not found: value Sum

How to resolve them? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [map expression in case clause in scala pattern matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051030/map-expression-in-case-clause-in-scala-pattern-matching)

Comment: @TzachZohar no it is not related to that question al all. Here OP's problem is not limited to pattern-matching. OP here does not understand `object`, `class` and `case class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala `case class` are like `class` with extra goodies + some other properties.

For a normal class,

```
class A(i: Int, s: String)
```

You can not create its instance like this,

```
val a = A(5, "five")   // this will not work
```

You will have to use `new` to create new instance.

```
val a = new A(5, "five")
```

Now lets say we have `case class`,

```
case class B(i: Int, s: String)
```

We can create a new instance of B like this,

```
val b = B(5, "five")
```

The reason this works with `case class` is because `case class` have an auto-created companion objects with them, which provides several utilities including an `apply` and `unapply` method.

So, this usage `val b = B(5, "five")` is actually `val b = B.apply(5, "five")`. And here `B` is not the `class B` but the companion `object B` which is actually provieds `apply` method.

Similarly Scala pattern matching uses the `unapply` (`unapplySeq` for SeqLike patterns) methods provided by companion object. And hence normal `class` instances do not work with pattern matching.

Lets say you wanted to defined a `class` and not a `case class` for some specific reason but still want to use them with pattern-matching etc, you can provide its companion object with the required methods by yourselves.

```
class C(val i: Int, val s: String) {
}

object C {

  def apply(i: Int, s: String) = new C(i, s)

  def unapply(c: C) = Some((c.i, c.s))

}

// now you can use any of the following to create instances,

val c1 = new C(5, "five")

val c2 = C.apply(5, "five")

val c3 = C(5, "five")

// you can also use pattern matching,

c1 match {
  case C(i, s) => println(s"C with i = $i and s = $s")
}

c2 match {
  case C(i, s) => println(s"C with i = $i and s = $s")
}
```

Also, as you are new to learning Scala you should read http://danielwestheide.com/scala/neophytes.html which is probably the best resource for any Scala beginner.